# ACRCloud Unity intergration, custom song

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio, sdk, acrcloud

I'm trying to set up ACRCloud with Unity and I'm wondering if I'm missing a step? I've downloaded the github file and I'm using the default Audio example scene, I followed the instructions for setting up custom audio and have added the Host, access_key and access_secret where asked but when playing the scene (on android phone) I get this error:

> {"status":{"msg"."http error:,"code".3000,"version":"1.0")}

On the phone, apologies if I'm being daft and missing something obvious, any advice would be appreciated :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your phone's network is available.
2. Check if the current app has internet permission. If you use Android, check AndroidManifest.xml.

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had an error in the code, my host was written incorrectly I'd copied spaces into the url removing the spaces fixed the problem for me.